# Key for controlling synergy on Mac

Tags: keyboard, emacs, synergy, keymap

My mac has **Control/Alt(Option)/Command**, and with synergy, each key maps **Control/LWindows/Meta(Alt)**. I want to change the mapping to **Control/Meta(Alt)/LWindows**.

Alt(Option) is key key name is written on the keyboard, LWindows is the one that pops up the window menu, Meta(Alt) is the key that I use for emacs for Meta key.

After reading [synergy page](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/), I found that

```
section: screens
    screen1:
    screen2:
        ctrl = alt
        alt = ctrl
end
```

is to change the key action for Control/Meta with synergy.

My problem is that it doesn't have the key name for LWindow, as I want to switch Lwindow/Meta(Alt) to Meta(Alt)/LWindow.

I mean I want to what to write for ????

```
section: screens
    screen1:
    screen2:
        ???? = alt
        alt = ????
end
```

Any hints on this?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is:
alt = super
super = alt

and put them both under your mac screen (screen 2 in this case).

This is because the windows key on windows and the command key on mac map to the concept super.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried it, but it doesn't work. I guess it might be a bug to be fixed. Thanks for the answer.